# Subtracting 1 from a Hexadecimal Value

Tags: assembly, hex, type-conversion, radix, twos-complement

Quick question concerning converting a two's complement hexadecimal value to hexadecimal so that I may convert it further to decimal. 
I have the following register value which is in two's complement hexadecimal form, as I see from the text, if I subtract one and then reverse the bits I should have the regular hexadecimal form.

My problem is that I'm not actually sure what you do if you're subtracting 1 from 0 and couldn't find anything in the text about it. Am I doing this right? Or do I not loop around?

ECX = 00076540
    00076540 - 1 -> 0007654F -> FFF89AB0

Comment: You are only supposed to do that for negative values, that is where the original sign bit is `1`. Your conversion makes sense in reverse, if you start with `0xFFF89AC0` then that's `-0x00076540` so `-484672`. (PS: `0x40-1` is `0x3F` not `0x4F`).

Comment: What is your intention? Do you want to flip the sign of the number? It is not just "converting". If the original number is negative, the result will become positive and vice-versa.

Comment: The same thing as usual (base 2, base 10, whatever, it all works the same), borrow.

Comment: So do I not do this step at all unless it's going to be negative like FFFC0888? Will I just go from 00076540 straight to decimal base 10?

Comment: Or do I do what Harold said and make it 00076540 = 0007653F?

Comment: And beware of the value 0x80000000, which, when you invert the bits and add 1, becomes  ... 0x80000000.

Comment: @Moxy: yes, for positive numbers you go directly to decimal. For negative numbers you negate the number, which you can do directly if you have appropriate instructions, or manually as you showed. Then print a `-` sign and the converted absolute value.